# Initializing several instances of a class inside a list with the iterator index

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a list containing instances of a class, and initialized with numbers 0 to 9. Here's what I do:

```
class Element(object):
    def __init__(self, elem_index=None):
        if elem_index:
            self._elem_index = elem_index
    def get_index(self):
        return self._elem_index

elements = [Element(elem_index=i) for i in range(10)]

print(elements[0].get_index())
```

Here's the error I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute '_elem_index'
```

Comment: What should `self._elem_index` be if `elem_index` is `None` (or some other false value)?

Comment: You don't always create `_elem_index` therefore you cant rely on it always being there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are conditionally setting `_elem_index` as an attribute of your instance based on the truthness of the argument `elem_index` you pass during initialization.

For `i == 0`, the first value produced by `range(10)`, the attribute will not be set since `0` is `False` when evaluated in your conditional. As a result the look-up will fail when it is attempted.

Be explicit in your condition:

```
if elem_index is not None:
    self._elem_index = elem_index
```

Comment: It would also probably be a good idea to set `self._elem_index` to *some value* even if no value was provided by the caller. It's a lot easier and more convenient to check for an attribute having a dummy value (like `None`) than it is to check if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Look closer at the code in your `__init__` function:

```
if elem_index:
    self._elem_index = elem_index
```

What your saying translated to english is, *If the boolean value of `elem_index` is true, give this class instance an attribute called `_elem_index`. Otherwise, skip this code and never define `_elem_index`*.

With that still in mind, understand that the default first value `range()` generates is zero

```
>>> list(range(1))
[0]
>>>
```

And in python zero evaluates to `False`

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>>
```

This means when you try to call `get_index()` on the first value in `elements`, Python raises an error because your condition in `__init__` failed.

To fix this you need to more specific and tell Python exactly when you want to skip the definition of `_elem_index`. Instead of doing `if elem_index`, use this `is not` operator test explicitly test if `elem_index` is not equal to`None`; `if elem_index is not None`. eg:

```
>>> var = 0
>>> if var:
    print("This will not run because zero evalutes to false")


>>> if var is not None:
    print("This will run because were testing if var is equal to None")


This will run because were testing if var is equal to None
>>>
```